# Adjust Window in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm starting with a development in WPF and C # I've learned some things since I come from Windows Forms but I've run into a case that is not how to solve, I thank my guide.

I get the following window menu through a call to a user control and paint it in a frame but looks like.

[image: Form]

You see the User control is above the additional menu to maximize the form remains the same, you know as I can solve ??

This is the XAML of the main window.

```
<controls:MetroWindow x:Class="Laboratorio.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Sistema de Control y Gestion de Laboratorio" 
    Height="650" Width="825"
    BorderThickness="0"    
    GlowBrush="Black"
    ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
    WindowTransitionsEnabled="False"
    Loaded="MainWindow_OnLoaded"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<!-- Menu -->
<Grid>
    <Menu Name="MenuPrincipal">

    </Menu>
    <Frame Name="Contenido"></Frame>
</Grid>
```

and this the the user control

```
<UserControl x:Class="Laboratorio.RegistroEquipo"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         Loaded="RegistroEquipo_OnLoaded"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="545">
<Grid>
    <GroupBox Header="Registro de Equipo">
        <Grid>
            <Label x:Name="serialLbl" Content="Serial:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="serialTxb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="89,11,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140"/>
            <Label x:Name="descripcionLbl" Content="Descripcion:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="263,11,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="descripcionTxb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="362,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140"/>
            <Label x:Name="marcaLbl" Content="Marca:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,49,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="marcaCbb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" Margin="89,49,0,0"/>
            <Label x:Name="claseLbl" Content="Clase:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="263,49,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="claseTxb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="362,49,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="externoChk" Content="Externo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,91,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="patronchk" Content="Patron" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="171,91,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <Label x:Name="articuloLbl" Content="Articulo:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="263,87,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="articuloTxb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="362,87,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140"/>
            <Label x:Name="articuloLbl_Copy1" Content="Responsable:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,127,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="responsableTxb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="89,127,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="nombreTxb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="263,127,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="239"/>
            <Label x:Name="observacionLbl" Content="Observacion:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,175,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="observacionTxb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="79" Margin="10,223,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="503"/>
            <Button x:Name="registrarBtn" Content="Registrar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="154,338,0,0" Click="Registrar_OnClick"/>
            <Button x:Name="salirBtn" Content="Salir" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="263,338,0,0"/>
        </Grid>
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I don't see where you have created an instance of RegistroEquipo in your MainWindow.xaml. My guess it that it is related to placing a Menu and Frame inside of a Grid, and the Grid is stacking the objects on top of each other (assuming this is where you connect your UserControl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn this;

```
<!-- Menu -->
<Grid>
    <Menu Name="MenuPrincipal">

    </Menu>
    <Frame Name="Contenido"></Frame>
</Grid>
```

into this;

```
<!-- Menu -->
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Menu Name="MenuPrincipal"/>
    <Frame Grid.Row="1" Name="Contenido"/>

</Grid>
```

Or just swap `Grid` for `StackPanel` whichever you prefer.

Comment: Thank you, Just what you tell me solve the problem. Let me get in "RowDefinition" 2 lines are added referring to the menu and the frame?

Comment: Ya you're just defining the number of rows your `Grid` contains. Otherwise it will just stack it's children on top of one another according to their z-index. When you add `Grid.Row="1"` to the second object you're declaring it belongs in the 2nd row of your `Grid` because the row count begins at 0. So 0 is first row, 1 is second row, etc, etc...

Comment: No worries, pay it forward to someone else some day. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not your application/xaml, it's a Visual Studio tool used for debugging.

When your application is running, go back to Visual Studio, go to the Live Visual Tree, and you can turn off "Show runtime tools in application" (the first button in the toolbar)

[image]

Comment: Thanks @sfm, I mean the menu of the application, the "group box" is above the menu, and edit the image.

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't catch that. Ignore this answer.

Comment: That's still a damn handy tip though.